# trying to set label text in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been tying to set text to a label but i get this error despite doing the same thing above it with no error, "AttributeError: 'Label' object has no attribute 'set'"
Here is my code and all help is of course appreciated :)
:

```
#creating the labels
text = StringVar()
text.set("-------")
plate1 = Label(DDFrame1,textvariable = text)
plate1.grid(row=0,column=1)
text1 = StringVar()
text1.set("-------")
owner1 = Label(DDFrame1,textvariable = text1)
owner1.grid(row=1,column=1)
text2 = StringVar()
text2.set("-------")
flags1 = Label(DDFrame1,textvariable = text2)
flags1.grid(row=2,column=1)

def changeText2():
    import random
    
    name = ["Vickie Vanfleet","Marcellus Amaker","Cyndi Beale","Roni Foti","Carolyn Sealey",
            "Lynda Ansell","Tomiko Kimbrell","Elfreda Bontrager","Melynda Mayberry",
            "Precious Nolan","Carl Harm","Trevor Olsen","Anamaria Christianson","Jonna Wagnon",
            "Alvina Flock","Sima Lablan","Talisha Fripp","Janey Smedley","Kelly Delpozo",
            "Shanice Folse","Sharice Wissing","Darlena Steele","Darlena Steele","Chana Tews",
            "Agueda Struble","Harriette Pacifico","Brandon Ellisor","Garry Foushee",
            "Telma Kellett","Randa Wojciechowski","Claire Snow","Willa Bankes","Arnold Fall",
            "Salome Ridings","Venus Tuner","Willetta Hendriks","Leana Straus"]
        
    name_outcome = random.choice(name)
    
    text1.set(name_outcome)
    
def changeText3():
    import random
    
    reports = ["rep1","rep2","rep3"]

    report_outcome = random.choice(reports)
    
    text2.set(report_outcome) #this is the line the error is referencing
```

Comment: How can we know, without seeing how `text1` and `text2` are defined? Clearly they are different. It looks like one is `label.text` (which has the `set` method) and the other just `label` (which doesn't)

Comment: Could you show a minimal exmple?`Label` doesn't have `.set` attribute.

Comment: If `text1` and `text2` are labels, then `text1['text'] = ...` or `text1.config(text=...)` should be used.

Comment: I'm curious why you think the `Label` widget has a `set` method. Did you read that in some documentation somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `text1.set(name_outcome)` with `text1.configure(text=name_outcome)`. Same for `text2` with `report_outcome`.

The `Label` method has no `.set()` method, you may be confusing it with the `StringVar` class which does. To work with something like that you would instantiate the label using the `textvariable=` attribute instead:

```
text = tkinter.StringVar()
tkinter.Label(root, textvariable=text).pack()
# henceforth usages of text.set("some string") will update the label
```

Comment: I've used StringVar when creating my labels ive updated my code to show the label creation and do you think you could look at it again. thank you

Comment: seems to work for me now other than not having a way to call `changeText2` and `changeText3`